# Canceling multiple subscriptions at once in RxAndroid - Android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I use Retrofit with RxAndroid to handle couple of requests in one Activity,

So I have couple subscription variables in the activity as public,

```
public Subscription sub1;
public Subscription sub2;
public Subscription sub3;
public Subscription sub4;
public Subscription sub5;
```

now in the `onStop` of the activity I want to cancel them all (if they did not finish).

Is there any way that we can cancel or unsubscribe all of them at once ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add them into a [CompositeSubscription](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/subscriptions/CompositeSubscription.java) and unsubscribe it in `onStop`.